# Getting current LTV of a PDF document with iText7

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am reworking an application which uses iText5 to resign near expiration documents with long term verification. My iText5 implementation looks like this:

```
//stp represents PdfStamer instance
AcroFields fields = stp.getAcroFields();
List<String> names = fields.getSignatureNames();
boolean result = true;
if ( names.size() == 0 ) {
    logger.debug("addVerification(): no signature names");
    return result;
}

String sigName = names.get(names.size() - 1);

PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = fields.verifySignature(sigName);
LtvVerification v = stp.getLtvVerification();
```

Now, I have most of the code translated into iText7, it looks like so:

```
SignatureUtil sign = new SignatureUtil(doc);        
List<String> names = sign.getSignatureNames();

boolean result = true;
if ( names.size() == 0 ) {
    logger.debug("addVerification(): no signature names");
    return result;
}

String sigName = names.get(names.size() - 1);
PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = sign.verifySignature(sigName);

LtvVerification v = stp.getLtvVerification();
LtvVerification v = doc.//what the hell do I do;
```

I'm stuck on LTV signature. I have document that is already signed and I need to get the current LTV signature. It can be done in iText5 but I didnt find a single method or class that would return me the LTV signature in iText7.

Is there a way to do this?